# HAPROXY http response 200 but response data missing

Tags: http, haproxy, wireshark

I have been working on troubleshooting mobile application issue, each and every request from mobile application will hit to domain lets say https://example.com with request payload in post body, this request will first hit to firewall then it will be forwarded to webserver which is HAPROXY in my case, and from haproxy request is getting forwarded to application server.

Issue : For many of the http request, response body is missing, but response code for same request is 200, I have checked at firewall and application server level, and it is confirmed that there is no issue at firewall level, and application server is returning data back to HAPROXY, but from haproxy somehow response body is getting removed. below i will show you both working and not working scenario

Working scenario :
[image]

TCP dump opened in wireshark,In working scenario, you can see, there is response data from haproxy to firewall and so data is reaching to mobile application and it is working as expected

Non working scenario :

[image]

here you can see that, request with payload got forwarded from Firewall->Haproxy->Application server, from application server logs it is clear that,application server has returned encrypted data to haproxy but when haproxy responded to back to firewall there was no data or data has been removed some how, it is creating issue to mobile application users and they are not able to use application efficiently.

HAPROXY is having frontend and backend portion, is there any possibilities that haproxy backend receives response from app server but same response was not returned to frontend part and hence it was not forwarded back to firewall ? however response code is 200